# Missing TLD Jar

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How do I resolve this error? I have the google app engine loaded on a microsoft platform. Is there a way to skip unneeded JARs? I am running the command below:

> C:\Users\tiger\Downloads\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.63\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.63\bin>appcfg.cmd update C:\Users\tiger\Downloads\jsonengine-0.2.20110102\jsonengine\war

Error Details:

> Apr 10, 2018 6:51:31 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
>   INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

Comment: What Java JDK are you using?

Comment: Also, can you please re-run the command with high-verbosity ([check the `--noisy` flag](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/appcfg-arguments)) and edit your post with the detailed error message? Watch out not to share sensitive information (tokens and such)